# Convert jQuery object to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to take a string in javascript, parse and replace an item within the HTML and then cast it back to a string. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to turn the new jQuery object back to HTML.

```
var compiled = '<div><div id="header-content">Test</div></div>';
$(compiled).find('#header-content').html('Woot');
var newCompiled = $(compiled).html();
//Need newCompiled to be '<div><div id="header-content">Woot</div></div>'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are modifying the dom elements created by jQuery, but is not storing the reference to the created element

```js
var compiled = '<div><div id="header-content">Test</div></div>';

var $tmp = $('<div />', {
  html: compiled
})

$tmp.find('#header-content').html('Woot');
var newCompiled = $tmp.html();

snippet.log(newCompiled)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

If you are just trying to add the newly compiled element to dom, then there is no need to create a tmp div, instead you can

```js
var compiled = '<div><div id="header-content">Test</div></div>';

var $tmp = $(compiled)

$tmp.find('#header-content').html('Woot');

$tmp.appendTo('body')
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
#header-content {
  background-color: lightgrey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?the console says `snippet is not defined` thank you

Comment: @Arun, Thank you very much.

Comment: This is just an extra step. I don't see the need to create yet *another* `div` just to use `html()` at the end to grab the original content.

Comment: @Purag we really don't know how OP is going to use the output... may be to store it somewhere or something else

Comment: @Purag we can also use `outerHTML` on the top object to get the output html... but only if there is only one root element

Comment: None of that is really relevant. You could just assign the result of `find().html()` into `newCompiled`. Plus, you don't explain what's happening here, and you encourage the use of extraneous code to accomplish a very simple task.

Comment: @Purag if it is for the sake of argument... the answer provided by you is wrong as it looses the outer div element....

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to a DOM object, do the text modification and then back to a string

```js
var compiled = '<div><div id="header-content">Test</div></div>';
alert($(compiled).find('#header-content').html());
//1-First convert it to a DOM element
var domhtml = $.parseHTML( compiled );
//2-Second do the text replacement
$(domhtml).find('#header-content').html('Woot');
alert($(domhtml).find('#header-content').html());

//3-Convert back to string the DOM element
var newCompiled = $(domhtml).html();
alert(newCompiled);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```